# polynomial regression machine testing error

Tags: regression, polynomials

I want to test a random number in `reg.predict([[hp]])`, but the program gives me this error:

> Found array with dim 4. LinearRegression expected <= 2.

This is my Polynomial regression machine code:

```py
predict = reg.predict(final2)
r2 = r2_score(test_y,predict)
print('R2Score :',r2)
print('percent :',int(r2*100),'%')
print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
a1 = input('Press enter to continue ...')
print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
x = 10
x = numpy.asanyarray(x)
hp = degree.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1,1))
zf = reg.predict([[hp]])
print(zf)
```

Please help me to find the correct code line ...

this is my full code lines :
[image: my code]

Comment: What is `degree`? Where did you define it? Can you provide a full **traceback** of the error?

Comment: yeh sure . i just edit it right now 
in question box

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots of the code and update your question by posting your (full-) code directly to reproduce the case.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)